# extract information inside span tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract PMC ID between "span" tag.

To do so, I used find element by xpath, but I'm facing the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:Message: Unable to locate element: /div/main/div/details/div/div[2]/details/summary/span[5]
```

Following is the link:

```
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/utils/idconv/v1.0/?tool=my_tool&email=my_email@example.com&ids=9811893
```

Following is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # this lets webdriver wait 10 seconds for the website to load
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/utils/idconv/v1.0/?tool=my_tool&email=my_email@example.com&ids=9811893")
pmc= driver.find_element_by_xpath('/div/main/div/details/div/div[2]/details/summary/span[5]')
pmc.get_text()
```

The output should be:

```
PMC24938
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css attribute selector then get_attribute to get the attribute value

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/utils/idconv/v1.0/?tool=my_tool&email=my_email@example.com&ids=9811893")
pmc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[pmcid]')
print(pmc.get_attribute('pmcid'))
```

Result:

[image]

---

Though you don't need `selenium` for this site. Use faster `requests` and `bs4`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/utils/idconv/v1.0/?tool=my_tool&email=my_email@example.com&ids=9811893')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
pmc = soup.select_one('[pmcid]')['pmcid']
print(pmc)
```